# Can we control a browser extension through jQuery or java script

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon

I installed fire-sizer add-on in Firefox, that can increase the size of browser for dual monitor. I want to know is there any option so we can call browser's add-on and request that to run. If it is possible so we can call it through javascript or jQuery.

Thanks
VD

Answer (score 1):

Depends from where you wanna call it:

- It is possible to create extensions for other extensions. XUL-overlay based extensions are easy to extend/modify/call, while extending/modifying/calling SDK-based add-ons is quite hard, but possible.
- If you want to invoke the add-on from a website, you're out of luck, unless the add-on already provides an API especially for websites. Due to security reasons websites should never be able to mess with add-ons (unless the add-on provides a limited, secure API to do so). FireSizer does not seem to provide such an API.